# What are the interval transforms in pymc3 for uniform distributions?

Tags: bayesian, pymc3

I've noticed that when using uniform distributions in pymc3, the sampler also scans over an `_interval` parameter as well unless a transform is specified for example:

```
with fitModel6:

    normMu  = pm.Uniform('normMu',lower=0,upper=1000)
```

will result in not only sampling over normMu, but also, normMu_interval:

[trace plot of interval](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gw5k.png)

[trace plot of parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRiyc.png)

Normally, when I am using an uniform prior for scale parameter like a normalization, I will of course sample over the log interval. Is pymc3 handling this for me somehow?

Cheers

Answer (score 5):

PyMC3 automatically applies transformations to bounded variables to put them on an unconstrained scale. The code for each transformation is [here](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3/blob/967f41f853946ae569178faf4b3e8c814382f70e/pymc3/distributions/transforms.py) and a very brief discussion of the automatic transformation of variables is found in the official PyMC3 [Tutorial](http://pymc-devs.github.io/pymc3/notebooks/api_quickstart.html#Automatic-transforms-of-bounded-RVs).

**Edit**

In case the link breaks/moves again, here's the bulk of the info from the Tutorial

> In order to sample models more efficiently, PyMC3 automatically transforms bounded RVs to be unbounded.
>
> ```
> with pm.Model() as model:
>     x = pm.Uniform('x', lower=0, upper=1)`
> ```
>
> When we look at the RVs of the model, we would expect to find `x` there, however:
>
> ```
> In [16]: model.free_RVs
>
> Out[16]: [x_interval__]
> ```
>
> `x_interval__` represents `x` transformed to accept parameter values between -inf and +inf. In the case of an upper and a lower bound, a `LogOdd`s transform is applied. Sampling in this transformed space makes it easier for the sampler...