# Convinient way for transformations in pymc3

Tags: pymc, pymc3

In certain cases `pymc3` automatically performs variable transformations (see [What are the interval transforms in pymc3 for uniform distributions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34577875/5142797), [what does the 'find_MAP' output mean in pymc3?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42146962/5142797)).

In answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/42170938/5142797 I found which transformations are applied. So in principal I can perform backward and forward transformations now.

But is there a more convenient way to perform these forward and backward transformations on automatically transformed variables? That would be very convenient, e.g. for `find_MAP` results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works:

```
test_model = pymc3.Model()

with test_model:
    u = pymc3.Uniform('u', 0, 1)

test_model.u_interval__.distribution.transform_used.backward(0.5).eval()
```